# Searching by length in minutes in Windows 10 File explorer search

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

To search for videos/songs longer or shorter than a specific amount of time, "length:" operator is used. But when entering a number without a specific unit, Windows File Explorer seems to only perceive a second when you write it as second x 10^7 (i.e. you have to type length:>130000000 to find something longer than 13 seconds).

When searching for very long videos, doing this is obviously a hassle. But I can't find what unit to use. I've tried ">5 min", ">5min", ">5minute", ">5minutes", ">5 minute", ">5 minutes" and Explorer perceives none of these. What is the unit for minutes or seconds in Explorer's search? Or is there no such thing?

P.S. I know that "length:short", "length:veryshort" types of operators still work; but those are rather limited.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the unit for minutes or seconds in Explorer's search? Or is there no such thing?

The unit is 1 second = 10000000. As explained [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/is-it-possible-to-search-for-music-files-by/15809efb-2a86-4280-850b-b9ad65b03deb):

> We can search by desired length if we use numbers such that 10 million equals one second.  So, to get a file of over 10 minutes, use 10 times 60 times 10000000 = 6000000000:
>
> length:>6000000000

1 minute = 60 seconds = 60 * 10000000 = 600000000

To search for files whose lenght is greater than 5 minutes:
5 * 60 * 10000000 = 3000000000
length:>3000000000

Answer (score 0):

How often do you have to do this? What's your level of expertise?

A simple PowerShell function could take an operator and vallues for hours, minutes, and seconds, and execute a search in Explorer. If you Shift+right-clicked in the background of the folder you wanted to search, a PoewrShell window would open to that location. Then execute **SearchByLocation** and be prompted for input.

```
Function SearchByLength {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $Operator,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int]
    $Hours,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int]
    $Minutes,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int]
    $Seconds
)


    $Filter    = 'Length:{0}{1}' -f $Operator , ([TimeSPan]::New($Hours,$Minutes,$Seconds).TotalMilliseconds * 10000)
    $Shell     = New-Object -Com shell.application
    $SearchWin = @($Shell.Windows()) | Where { ($_.Document.Folder.Self.Path -like (Get-Location).Path) -or ($_.Document.Folder.Self.Path -like 'Search Results in*') }
    $SearchWin.Document.FilterView($Filter)
}
```

[image]

[image]

After the initial search, return to Po werShell and run the funcftion again & it will update the Searcch window with your new criteria.

Ijust threw this together because the quesiton interested me. If you're interested, we can refine it. It could be added to your PowerShell profile so it would be available anytime you open a POwerShell winodw.

Comment: Ah, so it is not possible via preset Windows Explorer operators. I search by length often, but it isn't essential that I do it by minute. I just assumed Windows had an easier way other than making me type 6000000000 for 10 min. Thanks for the detailed way though.